# Open Silverlight OOB on url, if installed

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

Is there anyway to make the OOB version of my Silverlight app open(if installed) when i go to
http://mydomain.com/silverlightapp <--- where the Xap is loaded.

Just like a irc client opens when i go to irc://servername

but instead of prefix can my app open the OOB version if 
App.Current.InstallState == InstallState.Installed
when it's loaded in the browser?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Silverlight 4 there is no way of launching oob application from the url. Irc and other applications can register [custom url protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) to launch themselves from url. If you can create native application and install it on user's computer you could use it as a launcher for your oob application.

Comment: So there is no way for silverlight to invoke/open the OOB version of itself if its installed?.

Comment: no, not at this time. I think it might be considered as a feature for next Silverlight, but for now you are out of luck.